# java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getEnabledCipherSuites

Tags: java, ssl

jdk version is 1.7.0_05 ,web container is Apache Tomcat/8.0.15.
please help me!This error occurs only in the one million Java post request twice.Although the probability is very low, but it is a ticking time bomb,so please help me!
error stack is

```
 2015-04-30/21:21:41.555/CST [pool-1-thread-13] ERROR java.lang.NullPointerExceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:2355)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.getSSLParameters(SSLSocket.java:614)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.getSSLParameters(SSLSocketImpl.java:2441)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLAlgorithmConstraints.<init>(SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java:65)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.init(Handshaker.java:236)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.<init>(Handshaker.java:191)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.<init>(ClientHandshaker.java:104)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1249)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:639)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:613)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.xiaomi.xmpush.server.HttpBase.doPost(HttpBase.java:96)
at com.xiaomi.xmpush.server.HttpBase.doPost(HttpBase.java:51)
at com.xiaomi.xmpush.server.Sender.sendMessage(Sender.java:545)
at com.xiaomi.xmpush.server.Sender.sendMessageNoRetry(Sender.java:442)
at com.xiaomi.xmpush.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:339)
at com.xiaomi.xmpush.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:57)
at com.jiuyan.nc.push.MiTuiPushSingleServer.sendSingleMessageByClientId(MiTuiPushSingleServer.java:68)
at com.jiuyan.nc.push.MiTuiPushSingleServer.sendSingleMessageByClientId(MiTuiPushSingleServer.java:32)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at com.jiuyan.nc.interceptor.ExceptionInterceptor.handleFacadeException(ExceptionInterceptor.java:33)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at $Proxy21.sendSingleMessageByClientId(Unknown Source)
at com.jiuyan.nc.push.MiTuiPushListServer$1.run(MiTuiPushListServer.java:158)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: not a duplicate at all.  You seriously think the questioner wrote the class `sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl`?

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent version of Java 7?  1.7.0_05 is quite old.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Of course not. Most probably the null object got passed through, but the debugging is still the same.

Comment: Point taken. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: this error only occurs twice,and I can not find bug reports.

Comment: @BlastofTempest You need to post some code, specifically anything concerned with changing the enabled cipher suites. My suspicion is that you have called `setEnabledCipherSuites(null).`